# PHP - Multiple styled submit buttons redirecting to different sites

Tags: php, image, forms, redirect, button

I just want to have multiple buttons on my site which redirect to a certain section. This is what i got but it is redirecting to "error.php" everytime no matter which button I click:

```
<html>
<form action="error.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="variable" value="50" />
    <input type="image" src="play.png" name="Play" style="top:10%; left: 43%; position: absolute;" value="play" onclick="submitForm=('play.php')" class="submit_button"/>
    <input type="image" src="forum.png" name="Forum" style="top:11%; left: 22%; position: absolute;" value="forum" onclick="submitForm=('forum.php')" class="submit_button"/>
</form>
</html>
```

So basically I want button A to redirect to folder X and button B to folder Y. I have searched for hours but didn't find any awnser, please help!

Sincerely,
Max

Comment: What is `submitForm=('play.php')` supposed to be/do?

Comment: Its the php file I want to redirect to

Comment: What is `submitForm`? Did you write a JavaScript function called so?

Comment: Oh no you're right! Maybe it doesn't find the function Iam trying to create a java function for it. Thanks that was such a good idea :]

Comment: JavaScript, not Java, I guess. Anyway, you will probably need to return `false` in the function and then again return the value returned from the function to the input field in order to override the default submit behavior (which is to redirect to the page given in the form action attribute).